# Информация поражает тебя(,) как удар

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие, оборот-с-как, двоеточие-тире, запятая-перед-как

Нужна запятая? С одной стороны, можно заменить *ударом*, но, с другой — употреблено не в прямом значении. Кстати, что лучше: двоеточие или тире на месте вопроса?

`Жаль, что я уже не могу воспринимать это(,) как ты(,) (?) когда подобная информация поражает тебя(,) как удар!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Жаль, что я уже не могу воспринимАть это, **как ты**, — когда подобная информация поражАет тебя, **как удАр!***

1. Обособление оборотов определяется по расстановке **логических ударений.** Сравнить: *поражает как удАр.* В этом случае возможен перенос ударения на оборот.
2. В сложной конструкции лучше использовать **единый знак.**  Значение второй части пояснительное **(как именно?).**

Comment: Хм... Спасибо большое за ответ. А мне кажется, тут на разном основании: запятая закрывает сравнительный оборот, а тире, как вы и сказали, из за пояснительного характера. А двоеточие возможно?

Comment: Максим, я опять же предлагаю вам и всем пользоваться методом блоков по Лопатину. Куда как лучше! Значительная распространенность, три предикативные основы, обособленные обороты.  А ответ такой же, как у вас.  Только вам доказывать что-то надо, а мне необязательно) У меня ссылка на ПАС.  Да и отношения легко определить, так что и синтаксис  можно не уточнять.

Comment: А между какими блоками ставить запятую и тире? Какие отношения между блоками спровоцируют такой знак? Или мне лучше открыть этот вопрос для всех?

Comment: Я вам ответила. А с приемкой решайте сами. (Кстати, это у вас дополнительный вопрос, а не основной.) Если будете решать не блоками, надо грамматику точно определять, а она там не совсем стандартная. Я выбираю: запятая, тире, двоеточие, единый знак. Последний вариант наиболее подходящий. Тире недостаточно, двоеточие неуместно. Дело не в конкретных отношениях, а в том, что  другие знаки не подойдут  для такого сложного синтаксиса.